# BASH: Sudo Cat Multiline Commands to Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, maven

I want to append several lines of shell commands to a file owned by root.  I have `sudo` access.  In short I want to put this:

```
export M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.1.1 
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin 
PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

I tried this:

```
m2config=$(cat << EOL
export M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.1.1
export M2=\$M2_HOME/bin
PATH=\$M2:\$PATH
EOL
)
```

and then

```
sudo bash -c "echo $m2config >> /etc/profile.d/maven.sh"
```

But to no avail.  Does anyone know how to do this?  I have consulted many similar questions but none addressing this exact need.

Answer (score 28):

```
sudo bash -c "cat >> /etc/profile.d/maven.sh" << EOL
export M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.1.1
export M2=\$M2_HOME/bin
PATH=\$M2:\$PATH
EOL
```

If you don't fancy spawning a subshell, `sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/maven.sh > /dev/null << EOL` works just as well.

Comment: Thanks for the `sudo tee` tip.

Comment: note that the shell usually tries to expand variables (`$M2`). You can prevent this by specifying 'EOL' instead of EOL in the first line.